# How to do the SELECT with a Variables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table `myTable`

```
   Id       userID  month year login day
   1628325  812467  1     2015  1    6
   1628326  969054  1     2015  2    9
   1628327  812467  2     2015  1    27
   1628328  811602  2     2015  1    27
   1628329  952056  3     2015  3    2
   1628330  1082029 3     2015  5    2
   1628337  952056  3     2015  1    3
   1628338  952056  3     2015  6    4
   1628339  812467  3     2015  2    4
   1628340  1082029 3     2015  2    4
   1628341  811602  3     2015  4    4
   1628349  1081988 3     2015  1    4
```

I need to count the total number of login by date. 
I have 2 incoming variables :startDate and :endDate. So select should be something like:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y/%m/%d') "Day", sum(login) FROM myTable WHERE Date >=:startDate AND Date<:endDate ORDER BY Date DESC`

How to implement it?

The variables comes from jsp [page](http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/15/0728/h_1438087310_2858368_7f935457a4.png)

From the debug mode in Eclipse I can see that :startDate and :endDate variables that comes from jsp page - have the following format:

> Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 EEST 2015, Tue Jul 28 00:00:00 EEST 2015

When I run the report it is not showing nothing. Can be the problem with a time format representation? (%y-%m-%d) or (%y/%m/%d) or ..

Comment: where ara variables coming from?

Comment: you have to use group by too for that

Comment: Read about prepared statements in java

Comment: It should be only in SQL, for MyBatis migration:up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a date from the components.  One way is using `str_to_date()`.  However, you really should store the date as a date, rather than the individual components.  MySQL has good support for dates, so you should use these features of the database.

Here is one way:

```
SELECT str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year, month, day), '%Y-%m-%d') as date, sum(login)
FROM myTable
WHERE str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year, month, day), '%Y-%m-%d') >= :startDate AND
      str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year, month, day), '%Y-%m-%d') < :endDate 
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

An alternative that requires more processing but is easier to write is to use `having`:

```
SELECT str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year, month, day), '%Y-%m-%d') as date, sum(login)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY date
HAVING date >= :startDate and date < :endDate
ORDER BY date;
```

This is less efficient because it filters the data *after* aggregating the entire table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!